# Getting error for find webelement

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am tryting to get the element using the link text but unable to find the element 
getting error regarding the linktext

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can try locating element <a> first by using its unique title attribute, then proceed with locating element <span>

Comment: i have try but not working.getting same error

Comment: Can you add the code what you tried so far, So we can help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that since the text has a leading blank, it is not finding a "match."  I suggest you use partialLinkText instead:

```
WebElement myAccount = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("My Account"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In automation testing company we perform different approaches to find/get the web-element. In your case link text is not working because there is space before " My Account" text.

**So you can use Below approaches that can help you**

```
1.driver.findElement(By.xpath(//ul[@class='mega-menu']//li//a//span(contains(text(),'My Account')));
2.driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("My Account"));
3.driver.findElement(By.LinkText(" My Account"));
```